# (Short question) Modular inverse, there is no integer solution

Tags: modular-arithmetic

i just want to convince my self.

Does $10^{-1}\pmod {26}$ not have an integer solution?

Comment: No, because $10$ in a zero divisor mod. $26$ ($13\cdot 10=5\cdot 26$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you mean is to find an integer x such that $10x\equiv 1(mod 26)$
This is the same as finding $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $10x+26y=1$
However, since $\gcd(10,26)=2$, the least positive element in the set $\{10x+26y: x,y\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is $2$.
Thus there is no integral solution.